# Postgresql password change

Tags: postgresql

I want to use Postgresql 10.5 for musicbrainz https://bitbucket.org/lalinsky/mbslave/src

I have MacOS 10.12

I installed postgresql using these steps but cannot go from step 3. https://www.codementor.io/engineerapart/getting-started-with-postgresql-on-mac-osx-are8jcopb

I installed once and had added password for it. But I forgot it later and now I do not remember. I uninstalled and reinstalled it multiple times, restarted my laptop but nothing works. How can I remove or reset the password?

Comment: You have to edit `pg_hba.conf` to allow `trust` authentication for local connections.

Comment: Where can I find that?

Comment: In the PostgreSQL data directory. Don't forget to reload after you changed the file.

Comment: I do not have anything like that. I have only one folder in PostgreSQL 10 named documentation and it has html links. And in PostgreSQL 10 I have Application Stack builder, pgAdmin 4, Reload configuration and SQL shell.

Comment: Then you don't have a PostgreSQL database on your machine, and no database password as a consequence.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/ This is where I got it from (link in EnterpriseDB). When I type postgres - V in terminal, it gives me 10.5. If this is not the right link, can you help me getting the right one?

Comment: You have *the software* all right, but it there is no file `pg_hba.conf` on your machine, you have no *database*. In this case, use `initdb` to create one.